# How to prove that (ℤ\{-17, -7, -6, -3, -2, -1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 17, 2022, 2023}, ×) is a monoid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

How to prove that $(\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{-17, -7, -6, -3, -2, -1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 17, 2022, 2023\},\times)$ is a monoid?

Which numbers need to be verified to satisfy closedness for multiplication?
Not sure where to start with verifying properties?

Comment: Hint: What numbers multiply to form 2022 or 2023? Have a look at their prime factorizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then $\mathbb{Z} \setminus F$ is a monoid if $1 \notin F$ and
$$
x \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus F \text{ and  }y \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus F  \implies xy \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus F
$$
or equivalently
$$
xy \in F \implies x \in F \text{ or } y \in F
$$
It now suffices to verify that the set $F = \{-17, -7, -6, -3, -2, -1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 17, 2022, 2023\}$ satisfies this condition.